# Pay u SDK, Error parsing a meta element's content

Tags: android, payu, payumoney

While trying to do the payment, I am getting the following error. Please help me I have tried everything.
Scenario:
Go to credit/ debit card. Then enter test credentials (CREDIT CARD). Then it will stuck on a screen showing "**WE ARE PROCESSING YOUR TRANSACTION**". 
And the log shows

```html
05-27 15:00:53.746 8057-8057/com.payu.testapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.", source: https://mobiletest.payu.in/_payment (5)
05-27 15:00:53.746 8057-8057/com.payu.testapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.", source: https://mobiletest.payu.in/_payment (5) 
05-27 15:00:53.747 8057-8057/com.payu.testapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.", source: https://mobiletest.payu.in/_payment (5) 
05-27 15:00:53.747 8057-8057/com.payu.testapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The value "0;" for key "user-scalable" was truncated to its numeric prefix.", source: https://mobiletest.payu.in/_payment (5) 
05-27 15:00:53.747 8057-8057/com.payu.testapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.", source: https://mobiletest.payu.in/_payment (5)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the PayU support and i was getting the issue because the test server was down at that time. They told me to retry at that time and its working. Also if you are testing your application then use [these credentials](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/5.-Client-Side).

Comment: what is the exact issue you are getting? @AnshulTyagi

Comment: I am not able to pay from my own wallet with test code as many payment gateways allow.

Comment: I had used non-seamless method i.e. with PayU SDK and UI . Git link is here [https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/]